# Monitoring memory usage of other apps in iOS

Tags: iphone

I have serious doubts that it is even possible through apple approved apps, but I have seen a couple of apps in cydia that allow you to see how much memory individual apps are using and was wondering if that was possible without jail breaking the device.

The reason I am asking is that I am helping to design a "green" charger and accompanying app and the client thinks it would be beneficial to show the user what apps are draining their batteries or using the most memory to try to increase battery life.